# Generating data with different parameters according to other grouping variables

Tags: r, simulation, apply

I am trying to generate normal random variable with different parameters according to three other grouping variables. See example below for details (assuming I have 2 grouping variables for simlicity):

```
V1 <- rep(c(1,2,3), each = 3, times = 2) # first grouping variable
V2 <- rep(c(1,2,3), times = 6) # 2nd grouping variable
V <- cbind(V1,V2)
```

Obviously, I have 9 different cases {(1,1), (1,2), ... (3,3)}. So I want to generate V3 using `rnorm(n = 1, mean = x, sd = 20)`, where `x` varies from case to case.

I know I can use `if` , but for huge data, it's not going to be a good choice. I am using the following code (all means here are just examples):

```
V3 <- 
rnorm(n = sum(V[,1] == 1 & V[,2] == 1), mean = 1, sd = 20)*(V[,1] == 1 & V[,2] == 1)+
rnorm(n = sum(V[,1] == 1 & V[,2] == 2), mean = 2, sd = 20)*(V[,1] == 1 & V[,2] == 2)+
rnorm(n = sum(V[,1] == 1 & V[,2] == 3), mean = 3, sd = 20)*(V[,1] == 1 & V[,2] == 3)+
rnorm(n = sum(V[,1] == 2 & V[,2] == 1), mean = 4, sd = 20)*(V[,1] == 2 & V[,2] == 1)+
rnorm(n = sum(V[,1] == 2 & V[,2] == 2), mean = 5, sd = 20)*(V[,1] == 2 & V[,2] == 2)+
rnorm(n = sum(V[,1] == 2 & V[,2] == 3), mean = 6, sd = 20)*(V[,1] == 2 & V[,2] == 3)+
rnorm(n = sum(V[,1] == 3 & V[,2] == 1), mean = 7, sd = 20)*(V[,1] == 3 & V[,2] == 1)+
rnorm(n = sum(V[,1] == 3 & V[,2] == 2), mean = 8, sd = 20)*(V[,1] == 3 & V[,2] == 2)+
rnorm(n = sum(V[,1] == 3 & V[,2] == 3), mean = 9, sd = 20)*(V[,1] == 3 & V[,2] == 3)
```

Again my data is huge with many different groups, so this is not an efficient way. I could've also used `for loop`, but I am trying to avoid it. I am thinking to use `apply`, but not sure if it is applicable here or not.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What are values in `V1` and `V2` used for? You are only sequencing `mean` parameter from 1 to 9.

Comment: `V1` and `V2` are grouping variables, their entries could be {1,2,3,...} or (A,B,C,..}. I am using means from 1 to 9 for simplicity

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. This could work if I have `V1` and `V2` both sorted and all cases are repeated exactly `n` times ( here I have 2 repetitions each case). Real data are not sorted, and repetition are not the same for all cases.

Comment: Although the `mean` parameter is not sorted in real life, variables `V1` and `V2` still don't make sense. `(V[,1] == 3 & V[,2] == 3)` this part of your code will generate a vector of `Bool`s (`TRUE` or `FALSE`). Only on one position will be `TRUE`. You can accomplish the same doing `rnorm(n = rep(1, 9), mean = seq(1, 9), sd = rep(20, 9))` without those variables.

Comment: Where do the x's derive? Are they related to `V1` and `V2` grouping?

Comment: @Carles, Yes, I need that vector of `Bool` to give all corresponding cells a normal observation with similar `mean` and `sd` . And for `rnorm(n = rep(1, 9), mean = seq(1, 9), sd = rep(20, 9))`, it's assuming repetition are the same for all cases.

Comment: @Parfait, Yes `x` is related to each case. I am assuming each case {(1,1), (1,2) ...} is distributed as normal with different `mean`

Comment: in fact, I should've used `n = length(V[,1] == 1 & V[,2] == 1)` instead of `n = 1`

Comment: Do you suppose that parameters (`mean` and `sd`) are prepared for all combination of grouping variables ?

Comment: @cuttlefish44 Yes! I am generating the grouping variables first using `sample` with certain probabilities, then within each combination; I generate the continuous variable V3 according to previously determined distribution.